# How to re-show main window after closed in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I want to re-show the main window after closed when click my app icon on dock. Anyone know how to do it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement `applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:` in your application delegate. In your implementation, order the window back in. (Make sure you don't release it and it doesn't release itself when it gets closed.)

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428638-applicationshouldhandlereopen).

Answer (score 16):

In @implementation:

Make step 1

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
       [_window setReleasedWhenClosed:NO]; 
  }
```

where `_window` is your window that will reopen in future

Make step 2

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)sender hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag{
    [_window setIsVisible:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

where `_window` is your closed window