# how to make a window visible after close it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

My app is menu status bar app, I mean the app contains icon in menu status bar and a window. The icon in dock is hidden. what I need to implement is that after the user click the status bar icon, the app window shows up, but I don't know how to make a window visible programmingly. may be I have to use code like

```
[self.window show]
```

in my application delegate?

Comment: you should not release you window,  check this post [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13617998/1861897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
```

If you are calling from any action use `sender`.

In your case put `nil` in place of `sender`.

Comment: The sender parameter does nothing.  Any value will work, even the NSApp pointer.

Comment: Yes just for completing the syntax... :)